# mp3 stops playing after it worked a few times?

Tags: java, android, audio-player, android-music-player

I have a program that plays a short, 1 sec. .mp3 sound on every buttonclick (every time a different sound). After clicking the buttons a few times, the sound suddenly stops at all for the whole program, I have another background sound on another activity, If I start this activity after no sound is coming anymore, no sound is coming on this activity either.

code example of the buttonclickers:

```
mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.s1);
mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.s2);
i++;

if (i == 1) {
    mp1.start();
}

if (i == 2) {
    mp2.start();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you reset and release your media player when it is done playing!

```
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }
});
```

Also reset the integer variable.

```
if(i == 2){
   i = 0;
}
```